# chrome.storage.local.get search string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to use a regex or something similar to search chrome local storage, rather than having to match the entire key.

Lets say i have a bunch of keys , and I want to get the items where the key contains the string "fubar". So the keys could be "aaafubaraa" or "bbbfubarbbb" and I want it to find those items. Right now, I'm doing this:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function (e) {
    for (var key in e) {          
        if (key.indexOf("fubar") > -1) {
            console.log(e[key]); // do something with the item
        }         
    }
```

I tried this, which doesn't work because it matches the entire key:

```
chrome.storage.local.get("fubar", function (e) { console.log(e); });
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, as this way requires loading of the entire local storage into memory.

Comment: Not really. Unless you are the one that creates those keys, so you could save the keys you use in the storage, retrive them, check if any contains your fubar, and then get the local storage for that key

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with any of the storage apis, but possible with indexedDb and web sql (deprecated), both supported by chrome.